# Coc.nvim doesn't work correctly

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows, plugin-coc

Yesterday, I installed coc.nvim in vim on windows. I remember that it showed up the suggestion tab. But today, I removed go and visual studio, then it didn't show up anymore. I tried to reinstall Go, Visual Studio, but it still didn't work (no error message appeared) then I reinstalled coc.nvim in Vundle, then reinstalled coc-clangd, coc-json, coc-tsserver, but nothing changed.

Here is the gif explaining it.
[image]

Here is my _vimrc (I'm using Windows)

```
" PLUGINS ---------------------------------------------------------------- {{{
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree'
Plugin 'https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim'
"Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'neoclide/coc.nvim', 'release'
call vundle#end()
" }}}


"CONFIGURATIONS --------------------------------------------------------------- {{{

"let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf='~/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
"let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0

"Turn syntax highlighting on
syntax on

"Clipboard settings
set clipboard+=unnamed  " use the clipboards of vim and win
set paste               " Paste from a windows or from vim
set go+=a               " Visual selection automatically copied to the clipboard

" Disable compatibility with vi which can cause unexpected issues.
set nocompatible

" Enable type file detection. Vim will be able to try to detect the type of file in use.
filetype on

" Enable plugins and load plugin for the detected file type.
filetype plugin on

" Load an indent file for the detected file type.
filetype indent on

" Add numbers to each line on the left-hand side.
set number

" Highlight cursor line underneath the cursor horizontally.
set cursorline

" Set tab width to 4 columns.
set tabstop=4

" Do not let cursor scroll below or above N number of lines when scrolling.
set scrolloff=10

" While searching though a file incrementally highlight matching characters as you type.
set incsearch

" Ignore capital letters during search.
set ignorecase

" Override the ignorecase option if searching for capital letters.
" This will allow you to search specifically for capital letters.
set smartcase

"show partial command you type in the last line of the screen.
set showcmd

" Show the mode you are on the last line.
set showmode

" Show matching words during a search.
set showmatch

" Use highlighting when doing a search.
"set hlsearch

" Set the commands to save in history default number is 20.
set history=100

" Enable auto completion menu after pressing TAB.
set wildmenu

" Make wildmenu behave like similar to Bash completion.
set wildmode=list:longest

" There are certain files that we would never want to edit with Vim.
" Wildmenu will ignore files with these extensions.
set wildignore=*.docx,*.jpg,*.png,*.gif,*.pdf,*.pyc,*.exe,*.flv,*.img,*.xlsx    

"This unsets the 'last search pattern' register by hitting esc
nnoremap <silent> <Esc> :let @/=""<CR>

"Enable mouse
set mouse=a

" Fixes common backspace problems
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" Encoding
set encoding=utf-8

"for onedark
"Use 24-bit (true-color) mode in Vim/Neovim when outside tmux.
"If you're using tmux version 2.2 or later, you can remove the outermost $TMUX check and use tmux's 24-bit color support
"(see < http://sunaku.github.io/tmux-24bit-color.html#usage > for more information.)
if (empty($TMUX))
  if (has("nvim"))
    "For Neovim 0.1.3 and 0.1.4 < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/2198 >
    let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
  endif
  "For Neovim > 0.1.5 and Vim > patch 7.4.1799 < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/61be73bb0f965a895bfb064ea3e55476ac175162 >
  "Based on Vim patch 7.4.1770 (`guicolors` option) < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8a633e3427b47286869aa4b96f2bfc1fe65b25cd >
  " < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Following-HEAD#20160511 >
  if (has("termguicolors"))
    set termguicolors
  endif
endif

set background=dark
colorscheme onedark

" Use a line cursor within insert mode and a block cursor everywhere else.
"
" Reference chart of values:
"   Ps = 0  -> blinking block.
"   Ps = 1  -> blinking block (default).
"   Ps = 2  -> steady block.
"   Ps = 3  -> blinking underline.
"   Ps = 4  -> steady underline.
"   Ps = 5  -> blinking bar (xterm).
"   Ps = 6  -> steady bar (xterm).
let &t_SI = "\e[6 q"
let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"

" }}}


" MAPPINGS --------------------------------------------------------------- {{{

" Mappings code goes here.

" }}}


" VIMSCRIPT -------------------------------------------------------------- {{{

" This will enable code folding.
" Use the marker method of folding.
augroup filetype_vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType vim setlocal foldmethod=marker
augroup END

" More Vimscripts code goes here.

" }}}
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! "Does not work correctly" is not indicative of your question or problem, and makes it very hard to provide good answers. Please [edit] to clarify your problem. Also see [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) for tips on reducing your vimrc to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you try reproducing it with the minimal vimrc as suggested by coc.nvim github [issue template](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md)?